# Case Statement with Window Functions inside an Update Clause

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to deal with some older data that has a situation where new assignments were created after a rate change. I had an issue and solved it but I don't understand exactly what was causing the error.

Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
UPDATE #MonthTable
    SET StartDate =(SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN LAG([AssignmentStatus]) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartDate ASC) = 'rate change' 
                AND Assign_Occurrence > 1
                AND LAG(EmpID) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartDate ASC) = EmpID
                AND DATEDIFF(d, StartDate, LAG(EndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartDate ASC)) BETWEEN -3 and 3
            THEN Lag(StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartDate ASC)
            ELSE StartDate
        END StartDate
    FROM #MonthTable)
```

Current Solution:

```
UPDATE #MonthTable
    SET StartDate =(SELECT TOP 1
        CASE 
            WHEN LAG(AssignmentStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartDate ASC) = 'rate change' 
                AND AssignOccurrence > 1
                AND LAG(EmpID) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartDate ASC) = EmpID
                AND DATEDIFF(d, StartDate, LAG(EndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartDate ASC)) BETWEEN -3 and 3
            THEN Lag(StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartDate ASC)
            ELSE StartDate
        END StartDate
    FROM #MonthTable)
```

Would appreciate any insight as to why the initial subquery is flawed. Also for bonus points: #MonthTable is a temp table because of this update, I'm not sure if that's necessary or not. Maybe this update could just be a subquery of the #MonthTable query? [AssignOccurence] is calculated in the first query by a ROW_NUMBER() function.

Comment: *Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value* - surely that's pretty self explanatory?! You fixed it by limiting the number of rows with `top` - probably a `min` or `max` would be more appropriate - `top 1` with no order by clause will return a random row.

Comment: Thanks Stu! I'm aware of what the problem was and why this fixed it, but I'm not sure why this was returning more than 1 value?

Comment: Presumably it's duplicate rows in the table - you could run the select with a count(*) to see?

Comment: Your subquery selects EVERY ROW from #MonthTable. If that table has more than 1 row, your query will generate that error. Perhaps you intended to correlate it given the implicit self-join?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably rewrite this as the code below. I will say that this is just a guess because IDL the requirements, so if it isnt what youre looking for either "season to taste" or feel free to drop some requirements on me and Ill refactor. But I do assume you want the EmpID's to be updated based off their respective data and NOT the top 1 which is what your current query does. Which I might add I suspect is WRONG due to the fact you're not correlating it to any specific data element - you're just grabbing the top one of a random order.

```
UPDATE mt
SET StartDate = x.StartDate
FROM #MonthTable mt
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  
            EmpID
            , 
                CASE 
                    WHEN LAG(AssignmentStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartDate ASC) = 'rate change'
                        AND AssignOccurrence > 1
                        AND LAG(EmpID) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartDate ASC) = EmpID
                        AND DATEDIFF(d, StartDate, LAG(EndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartDate ASC )) BETWEEN - 3 AND 3
                            THEN Lag(StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartDate ASC )
                    ELSE StartDate
                END StartDate
    ) x ON mt.Empid =x.EmpID
```